# how to move file to trash in drive api v3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, drive, google-api-js-client, recycle-bin

I would like to use the gapi js SDK client to trash a file. But i cannot find a working example. I do not know where to place the trashed attribute in the call

gapi.client.drive.files.update({fileId: 'someId', trashed: true});
doesnt work.

Comment: I think that your script works. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the detail information about ``doesnt work`` and the whole script for replicating your issue? By adding more information, users can think of your solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I replicated the request you're doing and is working exactly as you have it. Can you add the error message and give details of your steps? Please.

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't seem to work. It responds `OK` but doesn't actually delete the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code is:

```
var id = "someId";
gapi.client.drive.files.update({
                "fileId": id,
                "trashed": true
}).then(function (evt) {
  //someAction after delete file
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The above examples didn't work for me, but I found [a more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62360470/how-to-move-file-to-trash-using-nodejs-and-google-drive-api-v3) that does:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.update({
  fileId: 'someId',
  responseBody: {
    trashed: true
  }
});
```