# How to move file to trash using NodeJS and Google Drive API v3

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

How to move a file to trash using NodeJS and Google Drive API v3.
Below lines are NOT working:

```
await drive.files.update({ fileId, trashed: true }); // not working
await drive.files.update({ fileId },  { trashed: true }); // not working
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- You want to move a file to the trash box using Drive API v3 with googleapis with Node.js.
- `drive` can be used for using the method of "Files: update" of Drive API.

For this, how about this modification? In this case, please include the request body to `requestBody` or `resource` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
await drive.files.update({ fileId, requestBody: { trashed: true } });
```

or

```
await drive.files.update({ fileId, resource: { trashed: true } });
```

#### References:

- [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)